# On a mastermind-kind game

Tags: game-theory

I am considering the following two-player game:

> Player 1 chooses a permutation of integers from $1$ to $N$.
>
> Player 2 has to guess this choice.
>
> At each step, he makes an attempt and Player 1 answers the number of correctly positioned numbers

I don't see how to compute the maximal number of needed attempt in the worst case (and if there is an explicit strategy) and the average number. Does this game has a known name, and is it studied somewhere?

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Comment: I recommend using gender-neutral pronouns instead of gender-specific pronouns: there's no reason a game-player has to be male.

Comment: @Greg Martin There is no special reason a game-player should be male, just as much as there is no special reason that a person engaged in doing math should allocate his or her attention to gender issues. Let us try not to be unnecessarily picky: our $x$'s and $y$'s are gender-free mathematical variables (I agree that it's a whole different story with chromosomes, in biology).

Comment: Gender issues are worth paying attention to because sexism and implicit bias cause harm to actual human beings, not to mention hurting science itself by pushing contributors away from it. Allocating our attention to gender issues is therefore, in my opinion, a necessary moral imperative. Never once in the history of human rights has progress been made through requests "not to be unnecessarily picky".